# How to store and retrieve data from an optional array of integers using core-data?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I've developed an iPhone app that is working fine except for navigating from one view to another without losing the data. I know that core-data is the solution but I'm a beginner in this area. I need to store and retrieve several arrays such as: var arrayName = [Int?] (repeating: nil, count: 9) in the exact order they become populated (0-8). How do I set these existing arrays up in core-data?

I've watched and read several tutorials, but none explain how to include an array (especially with integers) that already exists.

All of my code is working perfectly for this app. I only need to save the data.

I expect to be able to navigate from view to view and return with everything in place. Also to close and reopen the app where I left off.
Note: No need for error messages.

Comment: How much data is it? UserDefaults is another option if you don't have that much data.

Comment: Each VC uses 12 arrays like the one mentioned above. It's a golf scorecard that tracks 3 items (score, points & putts)  for 4 players for nine holes. Then is repeated in another view for the next nine holes.

Comment: You should design some model objects for that then, scorecard, player, ..., and use Core Data with an entity for each model. No need to store arrays.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know the results. It sounds good to me and I will have to do some more study on "model objects".

Comment: Joakim Danielson pointed me in the correct direction for my project. It took some time, but with more study of Core Data, I have almost completed my project with hopes of making it available soon! Now, how do I make sure he gets credit for the correct answer and advice?